# postgresql request database sql

Tags: postgresql, request

my db contains 2 tables category and item:

```
----------       ------------------
 category                item
----------       ------------------
id                 id  category_id
1                  1      1 
2                  2      1 
3                  3      2
4                  4      2
                   5      2
                   6      3
                   7      4
                   8      4
```

which request sql will give this result:

```
category.id 1 [
      item.id 1
      item.id 2 
      ],
category.id 2 [
      item.id 3
      item.id 4
      item.id 5
      ],
category.id 3 [
      item.id 6
      ],
category.id 4 [
      item.id 7,
      item.id 8
      ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want something like this:

```
select id, array_agg(category_id) 
from item
group by id;
```

Comment: with ARRAY_AGG, the key name is removed and we get only the value {1, 2}... But I want to keep the key name in the result : 
{
   category.id: 1,
     [
          {item.id: 1}, 
          {item.id: 2}
     ]
},
{
     category.id: 2,
     [
         ...

Comment: @Matrob9 - is key name always `item.id` for all values ?

Comment: Yes the key name is always item.id. (but it might be possible that i add a column in the table item, so it could be necessary to add another {key name: value} in the request later.